# can solr find all of the terms of a field of a document?

Tags: solr, solrcloud, inverted-index

solr uses inverted index to find the document from the indexed "terms".
but what I wonder is that -

is there any approach to know all of the terms which refer to a specific documents?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward index is what you were asking. [here in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing#The_forward_index). [here in solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DocValues)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this Luke tool](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases) which allows you to explore Lucene index.

It depends of your Solr version but you can also use Luke request handler with an HTTP request. [Here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) you have the documentation about this handler:

> To use the LukeRequestHandler, make sure it is defined in your
>   solrconfig.xml:
>
> ```
> <requestHandler name="/admin/luke" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler"/>
> ```
>
> Assuming you have this handler mapped to "/admin/luke" in
>   solrconfig.xml and are running the example on port localhost:8983,
>   visit:
>
> - /admin/luke
> - /admin/luke?fl=cat
> - /admin/luke?fl=id&numTerms=50
> - /admin/luke?id=SOLR1000
> - **/admin/luke?docId=2**